# Question related to calculus and tangent vectors to curves.

Tags: calculus

A bat moves along a path such that its position at time $t$ is $( 2t, t^2, 1+t^2)$ from time $t=0$ until time $t=1$, whence he leaves this path and flies off along the tangent line to its path, maintaining the speed he had at time $t=1$. What will its position be at time $t=3$?

I have found its speed at $t=1$ which is two units per second, the tangent vector at the same time will be given by differentiating the position which is $(2,2t,2t)$. Now how do I find the equation of the tangent and solve the question?

Comment: Find eqn of tangent at $t=1$ at the point (2,1,2) with direction cosines (2,2,2).

Comment: How will direction cosines help me in writing the equation of the tangent? The answer given is $(6,5,6)$

Comment: $(x-2)/2 = (y-1)/2 = (z-2)/2$

Comment: No. Sum of their squares can be made 1. In this case, if u divide $a=(2, 2,2)$ by its length, you can see that.

Comment: How do i proceed with the non parametric equation? I honestly don’t know.

Comment: Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let position vector be denoted by $r(t) =(2t, t^2,1+t^2)$ for $0\le t\le 1$ and hence speed at $t=1$ is $||r'(t=1)|| =2\sqrt 3$.

Tangent at   $r(1)=(2,1,2)$:

Direction ratios at $r(1)$ are $(2,2,2)$ and hence equation of tangent through $r(1)$ is $(x-2)/2 = (y-1)/2 = (z-2)/2=k$, say 
Assume that the bat reaches $(x, y, z) $ at $t=3$ hence we must have, 
$x=2k+2,y=2k+1,z=2k+2$
Distance covered by the bat in 2 seconds (from t=1 to t=3)=d=speed $\times $time=$4\sqrt 3=\sqrt{(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-2)^2}=\sqrt{4k^2+4k^2+4k^2}=2\sqrt 3k\implies k=2$ 
Hence, $(x, y, z) =(6,5,6)$